# Как поместить массив чисел в параметры метода JAVA

Tags: java

Мне нужно в параметры метода вписать массив. Возможно ли вписать именно содержимое массива, а не его имя? Мой код ниже нерабочий.

```
public class Para {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        printArray({3, 2, 1});
    }
    public static void printArray(int[] sequence){
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
            System.out.print(sequence[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (new int[] {3, 2, 1})

Comment: Что значит "вписать именно содержимое массива, а не его имя"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто использовать троеточие `...` для указания *переменного числа* аргументов (в т.ч. и пустого множества аргументов) *varargs, varadic argument*:

```java
void foo(int ... arr) { // то же самое что int[] arr
    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

тогда вызывать метод можно так:

```java
foo();  // 0 аргументов - пустое множество
foo(1, 2, 3, 4);  // переменное число аргументов
foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}); // массив аргументов
```

---

Можно использовать сокращённую форму инициализации массива в случае одновременной декларации и инициализации:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foo(arr);
```

Если инициализация выполняется отдельно, понадобится использовать `new int[]`:

```java
int[] arr;
arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Аналогично при возвращении результата-массива из функции:

```java
int[] bar() {
    // return {100, 200}; // ошибка компиляции
    return new int[]{100, 200};
}
```

Comment: По поводу терминов. Если глянуть JLS, то там `...` не оператор, а вместо `variadic arguments` используется `variable arity parameter`.

Comment: @siarhei987, исправил ответ, а `variadic arguments` попадалось где-то на engSO, хотя `varargs` более популярный термин